# Enterprise LAN based on Ubiquity

Tags: switch, storage-area-network, local-area-network, ubiquiti

I work for a small company with ~180 users.
We are planning a complete overhaul of our infrastrucure.

My question is whether Ubiquity equipment is suitable for our task (which is explained below), or we should look for other vendors.

The basic idea is building an hyperconverged WS 2016 DC cluster of 3 servers and connecting them via 10GbE links for SAN and LAN. This would require a couple of good 10GbE switches (mostly for low latency).

Also, we plan rebuilding LAN basing on a star design. I would build this all on two 10GbE switches, serving as an aggregation level switches for LAN, and as an access level switches for SAN, backing each other up. LAN and SAN will be segregated by VLANs.

Thus, these switches should also be able to route VLANs, so probably L3 is required (AFAIK L2+ cannot route VLANs).

My current choice:

- US-16XG / ES-16XG for aggregation level
- US-48-750W for access level (+IP phones)

Please advise, should I use them or decline this idea.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the budget to purchase some smaller models and set up a test lab to try them out in, benchmark them, do simulated failure testing, etc.?

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords I didn't have. So we analyzed our choices and decided to do it on Dell hardware.

Answer (score 2):

For iSCSI switches I'd look out for large buffers (at least 10 MB). As far as I know, Ubiquiti doesn't specify buffer sizes on their switches (or latency), so I wouldn't use them. Latency should be low for database or similar workloads, file or web servers are usually not that delicate.